# Bake in Blender 2.8

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, texture-baking, uv-image-editor

I have a small problem with the new Blender version 2.8. I wanted to bake some gauges with pre-applied textures (digits, aluminum and some basic colors).

The problem I have, is that it will not bake properly because it always gives me a black image as a result.

In object data I already added a second UV map layer, so nothing is getting messed up with the location of the pre-applied textures. I also tried adding some lights in my scene, which did absolutely nothing. In the bake settings I almost tried everything, changed it from *Combined* to *Ambient Occlusion* etc. but nothing seems to work, always the same result.

Since it's a little bit hard for me to explain I will attach some screenshots of my problems.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try changing in render/film/pixel filter and in dropbox change from Blackman-Harris to box.

Comment: Guessing from the attached images, the image texture node is not selected, you always need to have the image texture node selected in order for baking to work, regardless of what Blender version you are using, while in the attached images I see you have the uv map node selected instead.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work fine with Emission BSDF and bake set to emit:
[image: 2.80 tex bake]